# Web Api Cross Domain Basic Authentication

Tags: cross-domain, cors, basic-authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have setup a web api to allow cross domain access with Basic Authentication. When I make a cross domain GET request to the API, it works fine and I am getting token in "Authorization" header in my custom message handler. But when initiating a cross domain POST request, I am not getting the "Authorization" header that's why unable to validate the request.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Following is the code for my custom message handler for cross domain access.

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace MyWebApi.Handlers
    {
        public class XHttpMethodOverrideDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
        {
            static readonly string[] HttpOverrideMethods = { "PUT", "DELETE" };
            static readonly string[] AccessControlAllowMethods = { "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" };
            private const string HttpMethodOverrideHeader = "X-HTTP-Method-Override";
            private const string OriginHeader = "ORIGIN";
            private const string AccessControlAllowOriginHeader = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
            private const string AccessControlAllowMethodsHeader = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
            private const string AccessControlAllowHeadersHeader = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";

            protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {


                 var authHeader = request.Headers.Authorization;

                if (authHeader == null || authHeader.Scheme != "Basic" || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authHeader.Parameter))
                {
                    return CreateUnauthorizedResponse();
                }

                if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post && request.Headers.Contains(HttpMethodOverrideHeader))
                {
                    var httpMethod = request.Headers.GetValues(HttpMethodOverrideHeader).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (HttpOverrideMethods.Contains(httpMethod, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        request.Method = new HttpMethod(httpMethod);
                }

                var httpResponseMessage = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

                if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Options && request.Headers.Contains(OriginHeader))
                {
                    httpResponseMessage.Result.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOriginHeader, request.Headers.GetValues(OriginHeader).FirstOrDefault());
                    httpResponseMessage.Result.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowMethodsHeader, String.Join(", ", AccessControlAllowMethods));
                    httpResponseMessage.Result.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowHeadersHeader, HttpMethodOverrideHeader);
                    httpResponseMessage.Result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                }
                //No mater what the HttpMethod (POST, PUT, DELETE), if a Origin Header exists, we need to take care of it
                else if (request.Headers.Contains(OriginHeader))
                {
                    httpResponseMessage.Result.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOriginHeader, request.Headers.GetValues(OriginHeader).FirstOrDefault());
                }

                return httpResponseMessage;
            }

            private Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateUnauthorizedResponse()
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");

                var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
                return taskCompletionSource.Task;
            }
        }
    }
```

And i have registered the above handler in Application_Start as follows:

```
    namespace MyWebApi
    {
        public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
        {
            protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new XHttpMethodOverrideDelegatingHandler()); 
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter());
            }
        }
    }
```

At client side on a different domain project, I am trying to add a new record using following code.

```
     AddUser {

                var jsonData = {
                    "FirstName":"My First Name",
                    "LastName": "My Last Name",
                    "Email": "my.name@mydomain.com",
                    "Password": "MyPa$$word"
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "http://localhost:4655/api/user/signup",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); },
                    accept: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    failure: function (errorMsg) {
                        alert(errorMsg);

                    },
                    error: function (onErrorMsg) {
                        alert(onErrorMsg.statusText);
                    },
                    statusCode: function (test) {
                        alert("status");
                    }
                });
            });
```

And following is the code for my user controller.

```
    namespace MyWebApi.Controllers
    {
        public class UserController : ApiController
        {

            [HttpPost]
            [ActionName("Adduser")]
            public int Post(UserModel source)
            {
                    if (source == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
                    }
                    Db.Users.Add(source);
                    Db.SaveChanges();

                    return source.UserId;
            }                
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I too am trying to wire up a Web API REST service to allow basic authorization and to allow for CORS requests (GET's and POST's). Based on the article below I wonder if it is considered best practice to use this code in production. Have you managed to get this working? http://blog.bittercoder.com/2012/09/09/cors-and-webapi/

Comment: Unfortunately not. I didn't find a way to make it working. And due to the complexities and browser dependencies, I have dropped it to be a CORS enable WEB API.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that if I include basic auth credentials in my cross-domain (POST) XHR request, the browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox) rejects the request before it ever gets to my server - and this is true even if I specify `withCredentials:true` in my initial $.ajax() request. I'm guessing that there's probably something in the CORS spec which requires this. But I think the short answer is that you can't specify basic auth in CORS requests.

Of course, you can get around this in other ways, by passing userids and passwords as part of the URL proper, so I'm not entirely clear what they think they're gaining by restricting it, but presumably they have some reason.

Comment: Did you figure this out, I think it may be with the server not understanding the preFlight OPTIONS Verb. Make a request using OPTIONS as a verb, and the server throws a 404, which is what is happening in my application. I don't think this is a browser issue.

Comment: @TyroneMichael - There's quite a bit of dark magic in here yet, so I make no claims to have figured out anything definitively :-). But I was able to get my server understanding and responding correctly to the preflight OPTIONS verb, so I don't *think* that the issue was server-side. It's been a few weeks, but as I recall from my testing,   the only explanation for the behavior I was seeing was that the browser was blocking my XHR requests with basic auth. I'd love to be wrong - it's a scenario I'd like to work.

Comment: YA been experimenting the whole day. Installed the nightly Web-Api builds and seem to have gone off on a tangent. Tried to go this route [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). However still get a 404 when the browser tries to do a pre-flight request using basic auth. If I don't set the Auth header, everything seems to work ok and my breakpoints are hit.

Comment: @TyroneMichael - Yeah, that's exactly the problem I was running into as well. That would seem to indicate that it's not a supported scenario, and that I'll need to come up with some other way of doing authentication - presumably just by passing parameters in the URL or POST.

Comment: I got this to work. Don't know if it will help you, but I was decorating my controllers like `[HttpGet("dealerships/{id}/auctions")]`. If I added both `HttpGet("dealerships/{id}/auctions")]` and `HttpOptions("dealerships/{id}/auctions")]`, the problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate your controller with [HttpOptions]as well as [HttpPost]. Otherwise when it makes a request using the OPTIONS verb, it will throw a 404. So your controller would be

```
        [HttpPost]
        [HttpOptions]
        [ActionName("Adduser")]
        public int Post(UserModel source)
        {
                if (source == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
                }
                Db.Users.Add(source);
                Db.SaveChanges();

                return source.UserId;
        }
```